# Castle Windsor resolving a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

I have generic interface with some implementations.

```
interface IBaseInterface<in TObject, out TDetails>
{
    TDetails GetDetails(TObject obj);
}

abstract class BaseImpl<TObject> : IBaseInterface<TObject, string>
{
    public abstract string GetDetails(TObject obj);
}

class Impl0 : BaseImpl<decimal>
{
    public override string GetDetails(decimal obj)
    {
        return "decimal";
    }
}

class Impl1 : BaseImpl<string>
{
    public override string GetDetails(string obj)
    {
        return "string";
    }
}

class Impl2 : BaseImpl<Details>
{
    public override string GetDetails(Details obj)
    {
        return "Details";
    }
}

class Impl3<TDetail> : BaseImpl<DetailsGeneric<TDetail>> where TDetail : Details
{
    public override string GetDetails(DetailsGeneric<TDetail> obj)
    {
        return "GenericDetails";
    }
}

class Details
{

}

class Details1 : Details
{

}

class DetailsGeneric<TDetails> : Details
{

}
```

Using WinsdorInstaller class for register components

```
container.Register(AllTypes.From(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes())
  .BasedOn(typeof(IBaseInterface<,>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces()
  .LifestyleTransient());
```

Try resolve. Last two calls throwing exceptions, but I expect that they return components declared for base types

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Install(new WindsorInstaller());

        Details("test", container);

        Details(123m, container);

        Details(new Details(), container);

        Details(new DetailsGeneric<Details>(), container);

        Details(new Details1(), container); // "ComponentNotFound" exception

        Details(new DetailsGeneric<Details1>(), container); // "ComponentNotFound" exception           
    }

    static void Details<TType>(TType obj, WindsorContainer container)
    {
        var details = container.Resolve<IBaseInterface<TType, string>>().GetDetails(obj);

        Console.WriteLine(details);
    }
}
```

Where i am wrong? and can I fix it?

Comment: No component for supporting the service ConsoleApplication10.IBaseInterface`2[[ConsoleApplication10.Details1, ConsoleApplication10, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] was found

Answer (score 0):

You don't have  any component closed over `Details1` from what I can see...

Comment: Can I use component from base class?
For example, I have some decorators for custom user exceptions and get this classes using IoC
And I want decorate exceptions from WCF service, but they look like FaultException<TDetails>  (descandant from FaultException)
Maybe I can use only one class for process all FaultExceptions
Is it possible?