# Castle Windsor not resolving a contravariant generic interface (again)

Tags: generics, castle-windsor

Since I cannot comment the answer in this question [Castle Windsor resolving a generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120390/castle-windsor-resolving-a-generic-interface)

So I'm asking it again, I have exactly the same setup as in the question above.

This returns True:

```
var res = typeof(IBaseInterface<Details1, string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Impl2));
```

There is a component registered as

```
Impl2 / IBaseInterface<Details, String> = Transient
```

BUT if I do

```
var details = container.Resolve<IBaseInterface<Details1, string>>().GetDetails(new Details1());
```

It fails miserably with:

```
No component for supporting the service Test.IBaseInterface`2[[Test.Details1, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] was found
```

I'm using Castle 3.1 btw.

After some investigation I can see that there is an error in

```
DefaultNamingSubSystem.GetHandlersNoLock(Type service)
```

or

```
AbstractHandler.Supports(Type service)
```

Since my implementation is registered as a closed interface IBaseInterface but the Supports() method checks

```
ComponentModel.Services.Contains(service); // here service = IBaseInterface<,>
```

Obviously Castle cannot find the open generic service in my component services